# Preventing a hyperlink showing using CSS

Tags: python, css, django

A widget I use has this line of code as default.

```
<a href="javascript:map_Location.clearFeatures()">Delete all Features</a>
```

I don't want that hyperlink to be visible. I tried using -

```
id_Location_span_map a:link { color: white; }
```

But then I discovered there was other hyperlinks attached to the widget so I tried the following but none of them worked.

```
#id_Location_span_map href="javascript:map_Location.clearFeatures()" { color: white; }
/*#id_Location_span_map a:href="javascript:map_Location.clearFeatures()" { color: white; }
#id_Location_span_map a:link href="javascript:map_Location.clearFeatures()" { color: white; }
```

Does anyone have any other suggestions?

**Update**

Instead of {color:white} I will use {display:none}. But I still haven't figured out how to just apply the changes when the hyperlink is linking to a specific page.

**Update 2**

This code solves my problem. Thank you to Gubasek Duzy and https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/attribute/ for the help.

```
a[href="javascript:map_Location.clearFeatures()"] {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly you can use `display: none`.

Comment: That is more effective than me just making the link white.

Comment: Is it possible to only apply it when the href is a specific value?

href="javascript:map_Location.clearFeatures()"